# Oracle Table Access Full Even though Applying Filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to do SQL optimization. I have executed explain plan in TOAD for below query.

Even though i applied filer for TABLE1. It says **TABLE ACCESS FULL TBALE TABLE1**.

Can someone please help me.

TABLE1 - have 2 Millions of Records
TABLE2 - have 1 Million of Records

TABLE1 - When applyng filter say WHERE STATUS = 'I' - 100 Records

Column STATUS is indexed Column

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE 
TABLE1.STATUS = 'I'
AND TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

**Execution Plan :**

operation="SELECT STATEMENT" optimizer="ALL_ROWS" cost="69" cardinality="1" bytes="12"

operation="NESTED LOOPS" cost="69" cardinality="484" bytes="5,808"

operation="TABLE ACCESS" option="FULL" optimizer="ANALYZED" object_name="TABLE1" object_type="TABLE" cost="69" cardinality="485" bytes="3,880"

operation="INDEX" option="UNIQUE SCAN" optimizer="ANALYZED" object_name="ID_PK" object_type="INDEX (UNIQUE)" search_columns="1" cost="0" cardinality="1" bytes="4"

**When using ANSI :**

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 USING (ID)
WHERE 
TABLE1.STATUS = 'I'
;
```

Same cost and all.

Comment: Is there any index on the columns you are using to filter? If not, a FULL SCAN is the only way. Also, please swiths to ANSI JOIN syntax

Comment: Column STATUS is indexed column

Comment: Sorry, you already stated that. Can you please post the complete table structure, including all the indexes, and the explain plan

Comment: Is column ID also indexed?

Comment: Show us the complete execution plan. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: TABLE1.ID is not indexed column and TABLE2.ID is indexed and PK column.

Comment: I have updated Explain plan. Please check it.

Comment: @Aleksej. It shows same cost and all when using ANSI.

Comment: Analyze your tables again. Then, retry your query.

Comment: I have no idea how you created that execution plan. But that is not the way a typical `explain plan` is [displayed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9010.htm#sthref6524)

Comment: Are you able to also show the predicates? (I am sure it must be a setting in Toad).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the OP said he used Toad to generate the plans. I don't use Toad, but it's similar in SQL Developer. There are many options, both for what to be included and for how the output to be displayed.

Comment: I am note aware about predicates.. But it generating like this.

filter_predicates="&quot;CN&quot;.&quot;STATUS_ID&quot;=3"
access_predicates="&quot;CN&quot;.&quot;ID&quot;=&quot;CL&quot;.&quot;ID&quot;"

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the type of index on the STATUS column. If it will have only few distinct values, check if bitmap index works.
2. Specify the alias name for the table and use it in the condition.
3. Try using the index hint.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle mostly uses a cost/based approach in deciding what access path should be used. 
Depending on the index statistics (no. of distinct values, clustering factor, etc. ) the expected costs might be higher than the full table scan. 
You can check these expected costs e.g. by adding an `INDEX (table1, index1)` hint.
That way you can also check whether the index access actually improves the query runtime.
Note, that the optimizer also depends on other inputs, like system parameters and workload statistics - so, it might be that you need to consider these as well to understand this specific optimizer decision. But the index statistics I mentioned should provide a good start.